# filter dates not contained in seperate data frame

Tags: r, date, dataframe, filter, subset

I have three data frames,

df1= 2 columns, dates and amounts

df2 = 2 columns, dates and amounts

df3 = 1 column, list of bank holidays

I have combined DF1+2,

`FULLDF <- left_join(df1, df2, by=c("date"))`

Now i am trying to filter FULLDF to exclude the dates in df3. I have tried subsetting and filtering but neither are providing me with the results needed.

```
NOBHDF <- subset.data.frame(FULLDF != BH)
```

`NOBHDF <- filter(FULLDF[, 1] != BH )`

Is this something someone could provide some guidance on?
Thanks

Comment: try `anti_join` maybe ?

Comment: not heard of that one - will give it a go thanks!

Comment: you are welecome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the job (tidyverse way) :

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "date") %>% 
  anti_join(df3, by = "date")
```